# Python numpy array calculation

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have calculated a histogram slice using numpy histogram by `N,a = np.histogram(z,bins=50)`. Now my `a` contains the values of the 50 slices of `z` and `N` contains the number counts within those slices.

I would like to calculate `R-r` for `a`

I have tried

```
result = [R-r for R,r in zip(a[1:],a)]
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The code is fine, output: `[2, 3, 2, 9, 6, 22]`, "but it doesn't seem to work", can you be more specific?

Comment: @KobiK When I do the above I am getting `result = [1,1,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: @user3397243 That's not possible unless you've an array like [1, 2, 3, ...]

Comment: @user3397243 can you attach the code?

Comment: @user3397243: Why are you working with the second return value? That's the bin edges. If this were a graphical histogram, you'd be doing your math with the little ticks on the bottom of your graph instead of looking at the height of the bars.

Comment: You might want to reread [the documentation describing `numpy.histogram`'s return values](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Comment: @user2357112 yeah I have understood! I am making a mistake here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to use [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) for this:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,3,6,8,17,23,45])
>>> np.diff(a)
array([ 2,  3,  2,  9,  6, 22])
```

**Edit:**

Your code is working fine too, but you should not use list comprehension for this as NumPy already provides a function for this because it is going be both fast and efficient.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,3,6,8,17,23,45])
>>> [R-r for R,r in zip(a[1:],a)]
[2, 3, 2, 9, 6, 22]
```

Comment: @user3397243 Your code works fine for me, but you should not list comprehension if NumPy already provides a function for this.

Comment: The same does not work for a histogram slice!! i.e if I have `b,a = np.histogram(r,bins=50)` and I say `result = np.diff(a)`

Comment: @user3397243 And what does `a` contains here?

Comment: `a` contains the numbers of `r` that have been sliced in 50 bins and `b` contains the numbers counts within those slices

Comment: I have edited my question properly. please take a look